# Do some check on Associate in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is there a way in Laravel to do some check on associating?

For example I've `Home` and `Owner`, I would like on `associate` check if `Home` as already an `Owner`, and in that case I must execute some code...

Some suggestions?

Comment: How about giving us some code? What have you tried?

Comment: In all the code of the project is used the `associate` method like `$home->owner()->associate($owner)`, so i would like to avoid to create a setter method

Answer (score 0):

If you have your relationships set, you can just do an if statement

```
if($home->owner){
  // true if the relation exists
}
```

Comment: see my comment to the questione

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid an if statement by using a ternary operator and do it in a single line

```
$home->owner = $home->owner ? $home->owner : $newOwner;
```

Basically this is saying:

"The owner of this home is equal to this condition: Does this home currently have an owner ? Change nothing : Specify new owner"

The left side of the ":" is what to do when it evaluates to true. Right side is what to do when its false.

Note, however, that in some cases, a regular if is faster than a ternary operator. (at least in php)

Comment: see my comment to the question

Comment: responding to your comment on the original question, you'd also be able to throw a ternary operator inside the associate method. so it would be $home->owner( )->associate( $home->owner ? $home->owner : $newOwner )